# How to test for an index being out of range of array of Objects (Object[]) in Java?

Tags: java

I am making an implementation of the ArrayList class from scratch, using just Object[] and the standard functions. I'm trying to make a "size" method, which returns an int that is the size of the Object[] array.

```
public class MyArraryList{
Object[] Objects = new Object[0];

public int sizeOf(Object[] o)
{
    int i = 1;
    while(i > 0)
    {
        if()
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far. In the if statement, I essentially want to check if there's an error along the lines of "index out of range of array". I'm not sure what the syntax for this is. Can someone explain how to do  this please? thanks!

Comment: @Jared That other question was on how to find the number of digits in an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the length of an array using

```
objects.length
```

It would be possible to write a version of `ArrayList` where the length of the array is always equal to the size of the list. In this case the size method would just be

```
public int size() {
    return objects.length;
}
```

Such a list would be very slow. Because arrays are fixed-length, you would have to create a new array on every addition or removal for this to work.

`ArrayList` does not work like this. An `ArrayList` has 2 fields; an `Object[]` and an `int` called `size`. The point is that the length of the array is often higher than the size of the list, because there are unused slots at the end of the array. If you do it this way the `size` method is just

```
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

The most useful thing you can do is read the source code for `ArrayList` to see how it works.

> I essentially want to check if there's an error along the lines of "index out of range of array"

You *can* find the length of an array like this:

```
int length = 0;
try {
    while (true) {
        Object o = objects[length];
        length++;
    }
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    // ignore
}
```

However you should not use exceptions in such a way. They should be reserved for genuinely exceptional situations.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a try catch with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e, which was made for these kinds of instances.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/exception_multiple1.htm